# Why Javascript load into a function "functions as parameters" before than variables?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

The "fn" console.log comes up before than console.log of the two variables.

My function is that:

```
function test1(var1, var2, fn){ 
   console.log(var1, var2);
   fn();
}

function test2(var3){
   console.log(var3 + " it's here");
}
```

Call:

```
test1(123, "Hello!", test2("Look") );
```

Comment: What does `fn` look like?

Comment: fn() is test2, I think it was abvious

Comment: Before you can call `test1`, you need to know the values of all of its arguments. `test2("Look")` must be evaluated first.

Comment: You are calling test2 and passing its return value; you are not passing the function itself.

Comment: @Donovant: Nooo, it was not obvious. -1

Comment: @LiviuM. If you'd have __read the whole question__, you would have seen what parameters were passed to `test1`.

Comment: @musefan: I did not said you could not Eventually figure it out, but the question could have been much clearer from the start.

Comment: @Donovant It definitely was not obvious. Why would you write `fn()` if it was `test2`? Especially given that your `fn` didn't have any parameters and `test2` clearly needs parameters.

Comment: @EvanKnowles: Since when do parameter names have _anything_ to do with the names of the passed variables (/functions)?

Comment: @LiviuM.: eventually? as in, when you eventually read the question? I understand your concern though, a question of this magnitude could take days to read

Comment: Also, a "To broad" closevote is completely unwarranted here. The problem in the question isn't hard to find, and has a simple, short solution. (As seen by the answers). __far from__ _"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."_

Comment: @EvanKnowles: You would write `fn()` because `fn` is the name of the parameter... and if the code was working perfectly then the question would not be here in the fist place, would it??

Comment: Apparently there are other persons that agree with me (hence the minuses) I don't see the point of arguing on something which is my subjective opinion.

Comment: Then why bother commenting with a cryptic _"Nooo, it was not obvious. -1"_? If you're going to comment about your downvote, at least give a suggestion on how the Q/A could be improved, instead of simply saying _"Bad question -1"_

Comment: Why bother commenting on my comment? (I gave a -1 so that was my explanation, if you are not satisfied with it fine by me).

Comment: @LiviuM.: If we can't argue on opinions then what can we argue on? ...facts? now that would be a pointless argument. And the point of commenting on your comment is because you were wrong to downvote, and you need to be taught a lesson

Comment: @musefan: When you write a function you can't put as parameter a function with the brackets, that's an error.

Comment: @Donovant: Do you think I am not able to understand what's wrong with your question? You are mistaken. And to be pedantic, it's not an error to use a function call as a parameter. The mistake is that you didn't understand what it does

Comment: @musefan: You wrote "You would write fn() because fn is the name of the parameter", I haven't anything to add.

Comment: @Donovant: I am not sure you understand what you are saying... anyway, [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rdL3/) of when you can call a function as a parameter. Hopefully you will understand it... [this one too](http://jsfiddle.net/6rdL3/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `test1(123, "Hello!", test2("Look") );`, this is what's happening:

- execute `test2("Look")`
- Pass the return value from that function call to `test1`:  `test1(123, "Hello!", undefined);`

Basically, `test2` is executed before `test1` is called, because you pass the return value of the function as a parameter.

To actually pass the function itself, to execute "later", you'll need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
test1(123, "Hello!", function() { test2("Look"); });
```

Answer (score 8):

You're not passing a function as the third argument, you're calling the function and passing its returned value. It should be:

```
test1(123, "Hello!", function() { test2("Look"); });
```

In addition to get the the wrong order of output, you should also be getting an error when you try to call `fn()`, since `fn` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

code should looks like:

```
(function(){
function test1(var1, var2, fn){ 
   console.log(var1, var2);
   fn("Look");
}

function test2(var3){
   console.log(var3 + " its here");
}

test1(123, "Hello!", test2);
})();
```

BTW "it's here" - ' (single quotation mark) got more power then " (double quotation mark). It should looks like 'it\'s here' or "it\'s here".

and if you want to call the passing function it should looks like @Cerbrus and @Barmar said:

```
test1(123, "Hello!", function() { test2("Look"); });
```